# Center container according to width of its anchor elements in Jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, anchor, center

I need to center a container div which hosts a number of dynamic anchor tags. anchor tags vary sometimes I have 2 or just 1 and max I can have is 5 anchor tags.

I'm trying to get anchor tags's width by jquery to set width for the container.

but somehow anchor tag elements width is always returned as 0.  I tried enclosing anchors in divs but still no result. I must say that anchors are floated left, but I've included a clear at the end just like always.

I have no problem centering element in jquery once I get its width, but I need to combine the width of all anchor tags to then center the outer container.
.

Js fiddle here: [In jsfiddle I've created two scenarios, one with fixed width when container is full so it can be centered css margin 0 auto. but when less anchor tags cannot get their width to recenter container](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=qCOf8s7Rpy)

Comment: please fix you fiddle link

Comment: link is working fine, there are users connected right now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

[Js fiddle linked for solved solution](http://jsfiddle.net/#run&togetherjs=qCOf8s7Rpy)

problem was that while overwriting var storing widths it wasnt being done good.

in each iteration it should have been :

```
linksconitemswidth = parseFloat(linksconitemswidth) + ($(this).width());
```

and important to cast string var to int with parseFloat() or parseInt()